# ¿Cómo hago para que me funcione la lista para agregar, eliminar,modificar y buscar un alumno?

Tags: c#

No puedo agregar ni buscar el alumno en la lista. Cuando ejecuto el menu y elijo la opcion u otra cualquiera el programa no hace, nada como si fuese que el `switch` estuviera vacio espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace abm
{
    class Program    
    {            
        static void Main(string[] args)                 
        {
            List<Alumno> Alumnolista = new List<Alumno>();
            Console.WriteLine("bienvenido, elija una opción " + "\n");
            int opcion = 0;
            Console.Write("1º) Alta" + "\n" + "2º) Baja" + "\n" + "3º) Modificar" + "\n" + "4º) Consultar" + "\n");
            do
            {
                switch (opcion)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("Alta..");
                        Console.WriteLine("Desea agregar otro Alumno");

                        Alumno objalumno;
                        objalumno = new Alumno();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del alumno");
                        objalumno.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Apellido del alumno");
                        objalumno.Apellido = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Documento del Alumno");
                        objalumno.Documento = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Alumnolista.Add(objalumno);
                        Console.WriteLine("Alumno registrado");
                        Console.ReadKey();    
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Write("Baja..");


                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Write("Modificar..");
                        // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos //
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.Write("Consultar..");
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del Alumno que desea buscar");

                        foreach (Alumno a in Alumnolista)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(a.inscripción());
                            break;
                        }
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos //
                        break;

                }
                Console.ReadKey();    

            } while (opcion != 5);    
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo de la clase alumno

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace abm
{
    public class Alumno
    {
        public string Nombre
        { get; set; }
        public string Apellido
        { get; set; }
        public int Documento
        { get; set; }
        public string Nombrebusc
        { get; set; }           

        public string inscripción()
        {
            return "El Alumno" + this.Nombre + this.Apellido + "El Alumno fue inscripto : " ;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Esto se debe a que nunca asignas un valor a opcion y por lo tanto siempre se encuentra con valor 0. opcion = Console.Read(); con esto te tendría que funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás capturando los datos de entrada.
Además tampoco estás comprobando la integridad de dichos datos (por ejemplo admites caracteres).

Prueba a introducir lo siguiente al principio del bucle do/while.

```
string entrykey = Console.ReadLine();
if (!int.TryParse(entrykey, out opcion))
{
     opcion = 0;
 }
```

Dentro del switch puedes controlar la opción "0" como errónea.

Como mejora, también realizaría algun tipo de casting o comprobación antes de asignar el Documento asociado al objeto alumno.

Un saludo.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, ahora logre a que levante la opcion para agregar al alumno, si tengo pensando en agregarle alguna condicion al documento despues de hacer andar el menu con las opciones. ¿para poder ir a la opción de consultar al alumno agregado tengo que poner solo el comando de limpiar pantalla?

Comment: Lo primero que has de hacer es eliminar el comando Console.ReadKey(); ya que no hace nada. Agregar una una cadena indicando el texto "Introduzca una opción" antes de leer de consola para así saber que estás haciendo. Después de eso, una vez agregado un "Alumno" podrás consultar con la opción 4.

Answer (score 1):

Revisando el código se puede ver que no asignas un valor aparte de 0 a la variable opción y por ello no se ejecuta ninguna acción.
Añadiendo                 opcion = Console.ReadLine(); te tiene que ir.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace abm
{
    class Program    
    {            
        static void Main(string[] args)                 
        {
            List<Alumno> Alumnolista = new List<Alumno>();
            Console.WriteLine("bienvenido, elija una opción " + "\n");
            int opcion = 0;
            Console.Write("1º) Alta" + "\n" + "2º) Baja" + "\n" + "3º) Modificar" + "\n" + "4º) Consultar" + "\n");
            do
            {
                opcion = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (opcion)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("Alta..");
                        Console.WriteLine("Desea agregar otro Alumno");

                        Alumno objalumno;
                        objalumno = new Alumno();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del alumno");
                        objalumno.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Apellido del alumno");
                        objalumno.Apellido = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Documento del Alumno");
                        objalumno.Documento = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Alumnolista.Add(objalumno);
                        Console.WriteLine("Alumno registrado");
                        Console.ReadKey();    
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Write("Baja..");


                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Write("Modificar..");
                        // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos //
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.Write("Consultar..");
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del Alumno que desea buscar");

                        foreach (Alumno a in Alumnolista)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(a.inscripción());
                            break;
                        }
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos //
                        break;

                }
                Console.ReadKey();    

            } while (opcion != 5);    
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos.